# Swift app and python code fail to kill a certain process on mac

Tags: python, swift, subprocess, kill

I would imagine there are many different possible solutions to this very leveled problem. I am trying to make a swift-based mac app that can manage all my discord bots from one window. I have gotten it to turn on the discord bots successfully(using a global thread, NOT process objects). However, when I quit the app, I noticed the `Python` process launched by the app keeps running, and so does the discord bot. Instead of the app killing all child processes, it switches the parent process of the python to `null` when quit. I don't know swift very well, so I had some trouble getting it to kill all child processes when it closes(and yes, I know there is something with `info.plist`, but that is only for newer XCode versions than I can install). To fix this, I made the `applicationWillTerminate` code for `AppDelegate.swift` execute some python code to kill any process that mentions the files of the one bot that the app works with right now. The bot is stored in a folder called `roleManager`. Here's the python code:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import re
subprocess = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output, error = subprocess.communicate()
print(output)
roleProcesses=re.findall("roleManager.{20}", str(output))
#this regex probably could have been better but it works
PIDs=[i.split('\\n')[1] for i in roleProcesses]
for pid in PIDs:
    with open('killProcesses.sh','w') as file:
        file.write(f'kill {int(pid)}')
    os.system('sudo /Users/nathanwolf/Documents/coding/PycharmProjects/botManagerPythonSide/killProcesses.sh')
```

subprocess.communicate() returns a bytes object with a list of processes formatted like so(I'm pretty sure about this):

`CPU time` `command associated with process(like usr/local/bin/python3.9 some/python/file)`\n(not an enter character actually \n)`PID` ??

The sudo is only there because one time it said it didn't have permission to kill one of the running bots. This approach has had 2 problems. One time it killed its own python process despite not being in the folder roleManager and crashed PyCharm, most of the time it fails to kill the bot. For debugging, I looked for the bot's PID in `subprocess.communicate()` and it was associated with the following command:

`/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/SimulatorTrampoline.xpc/Contents/MacOS/SimulatorTrampoline`.

The way I see it, there are two pathways to a possible solution: get swift to kill child processes(not sure why that isn't a default), or get python to successfully kill the bot(is the above process related to this?). I would prefer the first one, but either one is fine.

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I found this on another question: 

You can just use killpg to terminate the process and everything in its group:

#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* ... */

killpg(getpgid(pid), SIGTERM);

Proper error checking should be done, of course, but you should get the gist. See the man pages kill(2) and killpg(2) for more info.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm thinking it has to do with process groups, but I can't figure out how to find the pgid of the app and all its child processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution from another stackoverflow question. I just had to execute the following terminal command:
`pgrep -f Python | xargs kill -9`. This kills all running Python apps, which are all going to be controlled from the app, so that works as a patch for me.